# Django cors headers not working with POST requests

Tags: django, cors, django-cors-headers

My stack is: axios for the javascript client, apache2 reverse proxy, gunicorn, django.

I have setup the `django-cors-headers` plugin.

I am able to perform GET requests to the django application. However, when I try to perform a POST query, I have a  CORS error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://[...]/move_item. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://[...]/move_item. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)
```

How is it possible that changing the http method breaks?

I have not set a value to the `CORS_ALLOW_METHODS` from `django-cors-headers`. Even if I explicitly do (`CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ("DELETE", "GET", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT",)`), the error persists.

My apache config is straightforward.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName [...]

ProxyPass /.well-known !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/[...]/fullchain.pem

Alias /.well-known [...]/www/.well-known/
<Directory [...]/www/.well-known>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LogLevel debug
ErrorLog [...]/logs/error.log
CustomLog [...]/logs/access.log combined
```

Gunicorn is used with this command `gunicorn myapp.wsgi`

How can I fix the situation?

Comment: Have you defined any domains in `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`? Or set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True`?

Comment: Please show your full CORS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@jub0bs

Parts of the `settings.py` relating to CORS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'my_app',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Versions:

```
% pip freeze |grep cors                  
django-cors-headers==4.2.0

% pip freeze |grep Django
Django==4.2.4
```